# UISearchBar for UISearchController iOS 8 regain focus after resignFirstResponder

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I'm using the new `UISearchController` in iOS 8.

I have a `UISearchBar` which I've added to the `titleView` and a corresponding results controller.

I have it set up so that when the search results are scrolled `scrollViewWillBeginDragging()`, I call `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()` to hide the keyboard (same as Spotlight search, Facebook app, etc. -- let's us see the results hidden behind the keyboard).

The problem I have is that I can't seem to be able to ***re-gain*** focus on the search bar. It should be as simple as just tapping on the search bar, but this seems to end the search completely, rather than refocusing the search bar to allow the search text to be edited.

I can't figure out why the `UISearchBar` isn't regaining focus.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out after much trial and error, the solution is surprisingly simple:

Just set `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false` on your UISearchController and it all works fine!

Comment: where? where to put that? i got UTAbleViewController, rows, navigation bar and buttons on that